# Run script that creates database tables

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to run a script like :

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CourseArchiveHistory` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CourseArchiveHistory` (
  `Id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `ArchiveDate` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `CourseId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `DepartmentGroupId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
.....
```

and so on. Right now I'm using a MySqlCommand with CommandText set to the script I'm trying to run. It's failing with

```
Parameter '@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS' must be defined.
```

Any ideas on how I could make this work ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The script runs without problems in the mysql workbench

**EDIT 2**

C# code :

```
        var con = new MySqlConnection("");

        var text = File.ReadAllText("script.sql");

        con.Open();

        var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
```

*Not production code.

Comment: Is it placeholders tripping it up?

Comment: You didn't declare your variables - i.e., `DECLARE @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS AS INT` or whatever.

Comment: See [Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html) in the MySQL docs

Comment: The script runs without problems in the mysql workbench

Comment: Please provide the C# code otherwise get rid of the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually called the command line mysql to run the script.

Comment: Hmm, Well then maybe before posting a question you should make sure it doesn't work then. Most programmers I know typically declare variables before they called them, it eliminates issues like yours. You code violates general programming practices and that is why I have down voted your question.

Comment: The code is valid in mysql. You clearly don't know this ... so why give an answer at all ?

Comment: if your code is correct then why did you post your question? You are still violating a major tenant of basic programming, sorry you code needs improvement! You should take a look at the link that was posted by  Conrad Frix http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html

Comment: I must say that's exactly how I feel about your answer. You didn't know mysql syntax and yet insisted that's the problem, you demanded c# code even though I clearly stated I'm using a MysqlConnection and setting CommandText with the whole script .... useless answer.

Comment: I wasn't the person who added a C# tag to your question, learn how to properly word a question on SO. #EpicFail

Comment: Ok, if this is how you program normally then I would love to see your code! Have a great rest of your day!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7101/discussion-between-sirrocco-and-mark-kram)

Answer (score 1):

You need to Declare your variables before using them:

```
DECLARE @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS INT
DECLARE @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS INT
DECLARE @OLD_SQL_MODE INT
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `Allow User Variables=True` to your `ConnectionString`.

Example:

```
Database=testdb;
Data Source=localhost;
User Id=root;
Password=hello;
Allow User Variables=True;
```

Comment: Please learn [how to format code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and read this [SO formatting help page.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).